# SSH.Net , recognize when shell ask for an input from user when launch command.BeginExecute()

Tags: ssh.net

i'm wondering if it's possible with SSH.net realize when the console or stream is asking for an user input.

Example:

```
SshClient client = new SshClient(host, plainUsername, plainPassword);
SshCommand command = client.createCommand("Telnet aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd");
AsyncResult asyncResult = command.BeginExecute();
```

The shell ask an input from user like "Username:" but command goes in error for timeout expired , i'd like to end async command and send the next one when shell is asking an user input.

How i can avoid that without using StreamReader of the SshShellStream, or without using command.result() into while cycle until i find expected answer?

It's is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why do you need to *"recognize user prompt"*?

Comment: User prompt is not the exact word :) i need to recognize when the shell ask for  an user input, so i know the command is "ended", and i can send the next command like username.
In this case, if i do BeginExecute and the shell ask me the username, the command stuck until timeout of shell.

Changed the title :)

Comment: @Orion77 Have you found a solution or workaround for that? I need to do the same thing...

Comment: no but i made a dll where i write and read until i reach the expected answer or a timeout...